# Python парсинг gdz.ru

Tags: python, парсер

Я написал код, но почему то на вывод идет только {}. Прошу помочь с поиском ошибки в коде.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://gdz.ru/')
page_content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
lessons_response = page_content.find_all('td', {'class' : 'table-section-heading'})
lessons = dict()
books_count = 0
for i in lessons_response:
    try:
        lesson_response1 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://gdz.ru'+i.a['href']).content, "html.parser")
        lesson_content = lesson_response1.find_all('a', {'class' : 'book book-regular text-undecorated'})
        title = lessons[i.a['title']]
        for j in lesson_content:
            class_find = j['href'].find('class-')+6
            class_num = int(j['href'][class_find] + j['href'][class_find+1].replace('/', ''))
            if not class_num in title:
                title[class_num] = {}
            title[class_num][j['title'].replace('\n', '')] = 'https://gdz.ru'+j['href']
            books_count+=1
    except(KeyError):
        pass
```

На вывод должно идти (примерно):

```py
>>>lessons
{
'Алгебра':{
    1:{
        'Автор1': 'Ссылка1',
        'Автор2': 'Ссылка2'
       }
    },
    2:{
        'Автор1': 'Ссылка1',
        'Автор2': 'Ссылка2'
       }
    },
'Геометрия':{
    1:{
        'Автор1': 'Ссылка1',
        'Автор2': 'Ссылка2'
       }
    },
    2:{
        'Автор1': 'Ссылка1',
        'Автор2': 'Ссылка2'
       }
    }      
}
```

На самом деле:

```py
>>> lessons
{}
```

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://gdz.ru/')
page_content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
lessons_response = page_content.find_all('td', {'class' : 'table-section-heading'})
lessons = dict()
books_count = 0
for i in lessons_response:
    try:
        lesson_response1 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://gdz.ru'+i.a['href']).content, "html.parser")
        lesson_content = lesson_response1.find_all('a', {'class' : 'book book-regular text-undecorated'})
        if not i.a['title'] in lessons:
            lessons[i.a['title']] = {}
        for j in lesson_content:
            class_find = j['href'].find('class-')+6
            class_num = int(j['href'][class_find] + j['href'][class_find+1].replace('/', ''))
            if not class_num in lessons[i.a['title']]:
                lessons[i.a['title']][class_num] = {}
            lessons[i.a['title']][class_num][j['title'].replace('\n', '')] = 'https://gdz.ru'+j['href']
            books_count+=1
    except KeyError as err:
        print("KeyError: {0}".format(err))
```

Обратите внимание на эту строчку:

```py
if not i.a['title'] in lessons:
    lessons[i.a['title']] = {}
```

У Вас не создавались имена предметов, поэтому была ошибка KeyError.